# Multiple voltages and currents required in one circuit

Tags: voltage-regulator, motor, voltage-divider, switching-regulator

I have a circuit with the following components:

- microcontroller - 7-12V, v.low current
- 2x Servo - 6V, 250mA
- Solenoid - 18V, 14 Ohm coil
- Geared motor - 9V, 6A stall current
- Power supply - 19V, 3A DC

From my research I have the following options on how to supply each component with the correct voltage and allowing them to draw enough current for the job.

- Linear voltage regulators - my current set up - horribly inefficient, low current capability (<1.5A) & thermal shutdown.
- Switching voltage regulators - fairly complex, (I don't know about the current capability).
- Voltage dividers - seems ideal except that, from what I understand, as soon as any substantial current is drawn the divider rule goes out the window...  Also high current resistors need to be used.
- Other?

My query is - are there any other options I have overlooked and what do people think is the best solution to my set up?

All answers welcome,
many thanks!

Comment: Regarding your voltage divider and current comment: It's not about "substantial" current or low current... Ohm's law holds either way. *Any* change in current is going to give you a change in voltage. If you expect the input current to change, a voltage divider is not the way to go, whether it's "substantial" or not.

Comment: Maybe you can power the solenoid directly from the supply. For the rest, DC-DC converters. You may need more than one power supply. Your geared motor, if it ever draws the stall current, is going to consume more than 100% of the available power from the supply, which may crash everything else attached to the supply.

Comment: A voltage divider is definitely not a suitable power supply for anything.

Comment: Thanks for the comments on the voltage dividers,  was a bit confused.  Are these used more for signal electronics rather than power applications then?

Answer (score 1):

> microcontroller - 7-12V, v.low current

This probably already has a linear regulator on-board. A linear pre-regulator may be OK at very low current, eg. a uA7812 would dissipate 350mW at 50mA.

> 2x Servo - 6V, 250mA

I bet they draw more than 250mA when moving. You probably need at least 2A peak, so a switching regulator will be required. The [LM2576](http://www.ti.com/product/LM2576) does 3A and only needs 6 external components (1 diode, 1 inductor, 2 resistors, 2 filter capacitors).

> Solenoid - 18V, 14 Ohm coil

This can be run direct from the 19V supply, with a ballast resistor to drop the excess voltage. A 1 Ohm 5W resistor would reduce solenoid voltage to just below 18V.

> Geared motor - 9V, 6A stall current

This will require a switching regulator rated at 6A or higher. A switching regulator lowers input current in proportion the increased voltage, but even so it will still be over the limit of your power supply. You need 9V*6A = 54W / 85% (estimated) regulator efficiency = **64W**, but the power supply can only put out 19V*3A = **57W**.

You should either get a bigger power supply, or use a separate 9V 6A+ supply for the motor.

Comment: - The microcontroller is the Arduino UNO and they don't recommend going over 12V.  Should've mentioned.

- Yes, you're probably right - the linear voltage regulator I have works well with a 1.5A limit until it overheats and goes into protect.  Thanks for the link to the switching regulators.

- The operation of the solenoid is very transient so I am happy to run this off the 19V

- Right you are! Switching regulators it is!  Glad I had all my options covered and there isn't anything that I could have used instead.  Time to learn about switching power supplies now I suppose thanks.